# How to Subset One Spatial Data Set into Multiple Spatial Datasets Based on Feature Name in R

Tags: r, subset, spatial, shapefile

I have a spatial dataset, polyline, that contains 115 line features and am trying to figure out if it is possible to select and save each line feature out into individual shape files using a loop or similar function?

I understand how to do this individually using subset (example below), however repeating this process 115 times seems like a waste of time and the power of R.

I am including an example of the data below:

```
trailname <- ("trail1", "trail2", "trail3")
trailtype <- ("mountain", "flat", "hilly")
parking <- ("no", "yes", "no")
shapelength <- ("835", "5728", "367")
trails <- data.frame(accessname, trailtype, parking, shapelength)
```

Here is a single subset example:

```
trail1 <- subset(trails, trailname == "trail1")
```

I would like to select each trail, and save it out as the name that appears under the "trail name" column i.e., trail1.shp

Comment: Have you tried `tidyr::unnest_wider()` or `tidyr::hoist()`.

Comment: *using subset (example below)* ... where is the example?

Comment: tidy::unnest does not seem to work on spatial files.

Comment: subset example added

Answer (score 1):

In base R, couldn't you us the `assign` function in a for loop to do this?

```
trailname <- c("trail1", "trail2", "trail3")
trailtype <- c("mountain", "flat", "hilly")
parking <- c("no", "yes", "no")
shapelength <- c("835", "5728", "367")
trails <- data.frame(trailname, trailtype, parking, shapelength)


for(i in 1:nrow(trails)){

name <- as.character(trails$trailname[[i]])

assign( name, subset(trails, trailname == trails$trailname[[i]]) )

}
```

**EDITED TO ANSWER OP'S COMMENT**

This should be do-able with a few tweaks. One item to note is that the example you provided is a data frame, while the `writeOGR` function takes...

> SpatialPointsDataFrame, SpatialLinesDataFrame, or SpatialPolygonsDataFrame objects as defined in the sp package.

These type of objects have data frames, but also other attributes that are likely of interests. Let's assume your data is in one of these accepted types. I'll use `rgdal` cities data as an example. If all we care about is saving the files outside of our R session, then skip the `assign` function and drop the `subset` into the `writeOGR` function:

```
library('rgdal')

#loading in data
cities <- readOGR(system.file("vectors", package = "rgdal")[1], "cities")

#taking only first two rows for this example
shap <- cities[1:2,]

 #where you want to save these files. This places it on your current working directory
location <- getwd()[[1]]

for(i in 1:nrow(shap)){

  # name of file
   name <- as.character(shap$NAME[[i]])

 # change shap to your 'SpatialPointsDataFrame' 
 writeOGR(subset(shap, NAME == shap$NAME[[i]]), location, name , driver="ESRI Shapefile")

}
```

Comment: Great, that worked. Is there a way for me to also save each individual file out using the writeOGR function within the loop?

Comment: See above for one idea

Answer (score 0):

There is a R package called ShapePattern. Look up the function shpsplitter. Seems to do what you want. Otherwise you can do it in other GIS software, see here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25709/splitting-shapefile-into-separate-files-for-each-feature-using-qgis-gdal-saga